# How to perform __eq__, __gt__ etc on int object in Python?

Tags: python, reflection

I am working on a class that requires multiple rules to validate against e.g. if certain pattern appears more than, equal, less than to a certain number. I have the output of this regular expression I am validating in a list and checking the length of the list. Now how do I call one of these methods (`__gt__`, `__eq__` etc) dynamically?

My approach:

```
func = getattr(len(re.findall('\d+', 'password1'), method_name) #method_name 
#can be any one of the values __eq__, __gt__).

if func(desired_length):
    print ":validated"
else:
    raise Exception("Not sufficient complexity")
```

For example, for `method_name='__eq__'` and `desired_length=1`, the above will result `True`. For `method_name='__gt__'` and `desired_length=1`, the above will result `False` (if a number appears in this string more than once).

But I realize `int` objects don't really implement these methods. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... Can you give an example func and some desired output?

Comment: Python 2 `int` uses `__cmp__` instead, but you should not be calling those methods directly anyway.

Comment: Yeah __cmp__ would be the way to go, but I was thinking of extending to support things like __contains__ as well. Can you elaborate why it may not be the best thing to call these methods please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `getattr` on the `int` instance here, maybe you should consider the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__lt__) module.  Then you can grab the comparison operator and pass the int instance and the desired length.  A full example would be something like this:

```
import operator

method_name = '__eq__'
desired_length = 1

func = getattr(operator, method_name)
n_ints = len(re.findall('\d+', 'password1'))
if func(n_ints, desired_length):
   print('Yeah Buddy!')
```

Comment: Thanks @mgilson. That worked. Did not know there was an operator module in Python. Is it supported in 2.6?

Comment: @brotherofmysister: `operator` is supported in 2.6, yes. See the linked documentation for specific function version requirements (look for *new in* entries).

Comment: @brotherofmysister -- Yep.  I have no idea when they added, but it was a while back.  If you look at the docs I linked, there is one or two things that is "new in version 2.6", but most of the "new" things are from all the way back in python 2.2 or so...

Comment: Ahh I see, somehow did not notice the version in the doc. Thanks guys!